# LiveCharts WPF Labels

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

Im using live charts to show stats from different region of data from my list.
The Regions dont have the same amount of Datapoints and labels will be different for each point.

My code:

```
public void MakeSeries()
        {
            
            SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();         
            var regionGroupedList = _recordList.Where(x => x.Region != 0 && x.Mmr > 0).GroupBy(g => g.Region);

            foreach (var region in regionGroupedList)
            {
                var MmrValues = new ChartValues<int>();
                List<string> DateLabels = new List<string>();
                foreach (var record in region.Where(x => x.Mmr > 0))
                {
                    MmrValues.Add(record.Mmr);
                    DateLabels.Add(record.Hero);
                }

                SeriesCollection.Add(
                    new LineSeries{

                            Title = (region.Key).ToString(),
                            LineSmoothness = 0, //0: straight lines, 1: really smooth lines
                            Values = MmrValues,
                            
                    }
                    
                );
                
                Labels = DateLabels.ToArray();
                DataContext = this;
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Right" Margin="0,45,0,0" >
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Title="MMR"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Game" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Works if I only use one Region (region1) as soon as I have a second Region (region2) it just shows labels from the region1 ony both lineseries but only as many as region2 has.

What am I doing wrong, is it possible to show each individual labels per lineseries?

Comment: can you show a picture of the problem ?

Comment: here is a link to a gif i made to show the problem [link](https://i.imgur.com/SMHPfX8.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert so I won't do an example, but maybe I think you should have mutiple axis X, so something like that:

- Fill an AxesCollection with Axis Object for each region
- For each Axis Object fill the Labels property with what you want.
- Bind your axesCollection with AxisX="{Binding AxisXCollection}"